# Working with non-ASCII Characters in Laravel 5 Router

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, eloquent, ascii

I have a `router` that uses a `controller` to fetch data from the database.

```
$router->get('/books/search/{query}', 'TextbookController@search');
```

When I get the data back and use non-ASCII characters in the URL, e.g.

`$query = tést`

```
public function search($query) { 
 dd($query);
}
```

Using a simple Postman `GET` request, the server returns `t�st`.

How can I get `$query` to be encoded correctly?

More code available at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr)

Comment: What is your database encoding set to?

Comment: @btl Database, tables and columns set to UTF8, the database returns everything correctly, done so by querying it directly with Sequel Pro. That's why I removed the database from the question as that doesn't seem to be the problem...